# Why are there 2 different angular function wrapping approaches and which one is best.?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I'm new to javascript and angularjs. But something that keeps me confusing is this.

Function A

```
(function (angular) {

    var AuthenticationService = function($http, $cookieStore, $rootScope, $timeout,UserService) {

    }

    AuthenticationService.$inject = ['$http', '$cookieStore', '$rootScope', '$timeout','UserService'];
    angular.module("app.AuthenticationService").factory("AuthenticationService", AuthenticationService);

})(angular);
```

I started some test examples with this one and in know in app.js i need to do something like this:

```
(function(angular) {        
    angular.module("app.AuthenticationService", ['ngCookies']);
    angular.module("app", ['ngRoute','ngResource',"app.AuthenticationService"]);
}(angular));
```

Function B

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('AuthenticationService', AuthenticationService);

    AuthenticationService.$inject = ['$http', '$cookieStore', '$rootScope', '$timeout', 'UserService'];
    function AuthenticationService($http, $cookieStore, $rootScope, $timeout, UserService) {

    }

})();
```

Now i haven't practical with Function B approach but i get confused on which is a better practical way and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both ways can prevent `AuthenticationService` being defined in `window`.

However passing `angular` as argument of `Function A` doesn't make sense except minification mentioned in estus' answer.

Function B is better because passing `angular` is unnecessary and may confuse others

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.